# Is AFR file from sovrn-merge.openx.net malware?

Tags: firefox

[image]

Anyone experience this before? It happens frequently to my Firefox browser. I checked the plugin and extension and there is no unofficial plugin.

Comment: It is not malware.  **[OpenX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenX_(company))** is an legitimate ad-platform.